# Preciso criar header e footer fixo para todas as páginas

Tags: html, css, header, footer

Sou iniciante em programação e não estou conseguindo inserir header e footer fixos em todas as páginas do site. Vi aqui no site uma opção com RenderBoy e RenderSection mas confesso que não entendi.
O site em questão é simples e tem poucas páginas. Há uma forma simples de fazer isto?

Answer (score 2):

Este código fixa o cabeçalho e o rodapé.

CSS:

```
footer {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: black;
 color: white;
 height: 40px;
 display: flex;
}
header {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: white;
 background: black;
 height: 40px;
```

}

HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <header>
   Este é o cabeçalho
  </header>
   este é o corpo
  <footer>
    Este é o rodapé
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

As regras CSS importantes para o efeito desejado são:

`position: fixed`

`top: 0`
`bottom: 0`
`right: 0`
`left: 0`

Elas instruem o código para fixar os elementos e em que posições.

A partir disso, fica fácil adaptar ao seu caso.